MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "officer"
Unable to populate() the hasOfficer field in the locations collections. I have been trying to figure out this for the past one hour.
officerModel.ts
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const officerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    currentLocationId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "location", required: true},
    KGID: {type: Number, required: true},
    dateOfJoining: {type: Date, required: true},
});

const officerModel = mongoose.model("officer", officerSchema);
export default officerModel;

locationModel.ts
import mongoose from "mongoose";


const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    district: {type: String, required: true},
    taluk: {type: String, required: true},
    gramPanchayat: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    hasOfficer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "officer"}
},
    {timestamps: true})


const locationModel = mongoose.model("location", locationSchema);
export default locationModel;

i searched it everywhere and every single time it was the case of letter casing of model referenced in the schema. But in my case the casing is also right. I don't know where am i going wrong.

I figured out the answer from another stackoverflow post.
changing the model reference(ref) from the string to imported model solved it.
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import officerModel from "./Officer";


const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    district: {type: String, required: true},
    taluk: {type: String, required: true},
    gramPanchayat: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    hasOfficer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: officerModel}
},
    {timestamps: true})


const locationModel = mongoose.model("location", locationSchema);
export default locationModel;

